# ImportError when trying to list available Language Models (LLMs) and Chat Models using langchain

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain, large-language-model, chatgpt-api

I'm currently working on a project that involves Language Models (LLMs) and Chat Models, and I'm using the `langchain` library in Python to list available models. However, I'm encountering an `ImportError` when running the code.

Here's the code snippet I'm using:

```py
from langchain.chat_models import list_available_models
model_names = list_available_models()
print(model_names)
```

The error message I receive is as follows:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'list_available_models' from 'langchain.chat_models' (c:\Users\Edge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\langchain\chat_models\__init__.py)
```

I've double-checked the library and the code, but I can't seem to find a solution to this issue. Could someone please help me understand what might be causing this `ImportError` and how I can resolve it?

---

Answer (score 0):

As I know, the package `langchain.chat_models` doesn't have this function `list_available_models`. If you want to see the available models, you can go to this file `c:\Users\Edge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\langchain\chat_models\__init__.py` and you can see all the available models like this:

```
__all__ = [
    "ChatOpenAI",
    "BedrockChat",
    "AzureChatOpenAI",
    "FakeListChatModel",
    "PromptLayerChatOpenAI",
    "ChatDatabricks",
    "ChatEverlyAI",
    "ChatAnthropic",
    "ChatCohere",
    "ChatGooglePalm",
    "ChatMlflow",
    "ChatMLflowAIGateway",
    "ChatOllama",
    "ChatVertexAI",
    "JinaChat",
    "HumanInputChatModel",
    "MiniMaxChat",
    "ChatAnyscale",
    "ChatLiteLLM",
    "ErnieBotChat",
    "ChatJavelinAIGateway",
    "ChatKonko",
    "PaiEasChatEndpoint",
    "QianfanChatEndpoint",
    "ChatFireworks",
    "ChatYandexGPT",
    "ChatBaichuan",
    "ChatHunyuan",
    "GigaChat",
    "VolcEngineMaasChat",
]
```

If you want to use `ChatOpenai`, you can use:

```
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI

llm = ChatOpenAI(openai_api_key="...")
```